# Lista circular doblemente enlazada

Tags: c, lista

Este código trata de implementar una lista circular doblemente enlazada

El código compila, no arroja error, pero se traba al intentar ingresar números

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct lista
{
    int info;
    struct lista *sig,*ant;
}*CAB=NULL,*AUX=NULL,*Q=NULL,*P=NULL,*F=NULL,*QD=NULL,*FD=NULL;

int main() {
    void insertard(void);
    void extraerd(void);
    void visualizard(void);
    void visualizari(void);
    void eliminardespues();
    void eliminarantes();
    char opc;
    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("___________________________________________________\n");
        printf("_¡¡¡MENU DE LISTA CIRCULAR DOBLEMENTE ENLAZADA!!!__\n");
        printf("___________________________________________________\n");
        printf("____________SELECCIONE UNA OPCION__________________\n");
        printf("___________________________________________________\n");
        printf("___________________________________________________\n");
        printf("__________1) INSERTAR______________________________\n");
        printf("__________2) VISUALIZAR ASCENDIENTE________________\n");
        printf("__________3) VISUALIZAR DESCENDIENTE_______________\n");
        printf("__________4) INGRESAR Y ELIMINAR SIGUIENTE_________\n");
        printf("__________5) INGRESAR Y ELIMINAR ANTERIOR__________\n");
        printf("__________6) SALIR_________________________________\n");
        printf("___________________________________________________\n");
        opc=getch();
        switch(opc)
        {
        case '1':
            insertard();
            break;
        case '2':
            visualizard();
            break;
        case '3':
            visualizari();
            break;
        case '4':
            eliminardespues();
            break;
        case '5':
            eliminarantes();
            break;           
        }
    } while(opc!='6');
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void insertard(void)
{
    P=CAB;
    AUX=(struct lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    system("cls");
    printf("INGRESE UN NUMERO ENTERO: ");
    scanf("%d",&AUX->info);
    AUX->sig=CAB;
    AUX->ant=CAB;
    F=AUX;
    if(CAB==NULL){
        CAB=AUX;
    }else{
        while (P->sig!=CAB){
            P=P->sig;
    }
    } 
        P->sig=AUX;
        AUX->ant=P;
        CAB->ant=AUX;
}

void eliminardespues(){
    int x;
    system("cls");
    printf("INGRESE UN NUMERO PARA ELIMINAR EL SIGUIENTE:");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    FD=CAB;
    QD=CAB;
    while(FD->info!=x&&FD->sig!=CAB){
    FD=FD->sig;
    }QD=FD->sig;

    if(FD->sig==CAB&&FD->info!=x){
        printf("\nEL NUMERO INGRESADO NO SE ENCUENTA EN LA LISTA");
    }else{
        if(FD->info==x){
            FD->sig=QD->sig;
            (QD->sig)->ant=FD;
            printf("\nELIMINADO %d",QD->info);
            free(Q);
        }
    }
    getch();
}

void eliminarantes()
{
    int x;
    system("cls");
    printf("INGRESE UN NUMERO PARA ELIMINAR EL ANTERIOR");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    FD=CAB;
    QD=CAB;
    while (FD->info!=x&&FD->sig!=CAB){
        FD=FD->sig;
    }QD=FD->ant;
    if(FD->sig==CAB&&FD->info!=x){
        printf("\nEL NUMERO INGRESADO NO SE ENCUENTA EN LA LISTA");
    }else{
        if(FD->info==x){
            FD->ant=QD->ant;
            (QD->ant)->sig=FD;
            printf("\nELIMINADO %d",QD->info);
            free(Q);
        }
    }
    getch();
}

void visualizard(void)
{
    system("cls");
    if(CAB==NULL){
        printf("LISTA VACIA");
        getchar();
        return;
    }
    AUX=CAB;
    printf("LISTA:\n\n");
    while(AUX->sig!=CAB){
        printf("-> %d\n",AUX->info);
        AUX=AUX->sig;
    }
    if(AUX->sig==CAB){
        printf("-> %d\n",AUX->info);
    }
    getch();
}

void visualizari(void){
    system("cls");
    if(CAB==NULL){
        printf("LISTA VACIA");
        getchar();
        return;
    }
    AUX=CAB->ant;
    printf("LISTA:\n\n");
    do{
        printf("-> %d\n",AUX->info);
        AUX=AUX->ant;
    }while(AUX->sig!=CAB);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Por favor, no edites la pregunta para eliminar la pregunta inicial y hacer otras diferentes... si haces eso las respuestas que ya se hayan publicado no sirven de nada. Para eso, como has hecho esta mañana, publica preguntas nuevas... pero añade en esas preguntas toda la información que sea necesaria

Comment: Hecho, desecho los cambios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código tenía varios errores lógicos, variables demás, etc. Aquí aparece funcionado sin problemas

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<winsock.h>

void clrscr();

//ESTO ES PARA CREAR LA LISTA
struct lista
{
    int info;
    struct lista *sig,*ant;
}*CAB=NULL,*AUX=NULL,*P=NULL,*FD=NULL,*QD=NULL,*Fd=NULL,*Qd=NULL;

int main()
{
    void insertard(void);
    void extraerd(void);
    void visualizard(void);
    void visualizari(void);
    void eliminardespues();
    void eliminarantes();

    char opc;
    do{
        clrscr();
        printf("____________________________________________________\n");
        printf("|_???MENU DE LISTA CIRCULAR DOBLEMENTE ENLAZADA!!!__|\n");
        printf("|___________________________________________________|\n");
        printf("|___________________________________________________|\n");
        printf("|___________SELECCIONE UNA OPCION___________________|\n");
        printf("|___________________________________________________|\n");
        printf("|___________________________________________________|\n");
        printf("|_________1) INSERTAR_______________________________|\n");
        printf("|_________2) VISUALIZAR ASCENDENTE__________________|\n");
        printf("|_________3) VISUALIZAR DESCENDENTE_________________|\n");
        printf("|_________4) INGRESAR Y ELIMINAR SIGUIENTE__________|\n");
        printf("|_________5) INGRESAR Y ELIMINAR ANTERIOR___________|\n");
        printf("|_________6) SALIR__________________________________|\n");
        printf("|___________________________________________________|\n");
        opc=getch();
        switch(opc)
        {

        case '1':
            insertard();
            break;

        case '2':
            visualizard();
            break;

        case '3':
            visualizari();
            break;

        case '4':
            eliminardespues();
            break;

            case'5':
                eliminarantes();
                break;
        }

    }while(opc!='6');
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void insertard(void)
{
    P=CAB; /* primera ejecuci?n de este m?todo P = NULL */
    AUX=(struct lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    clrscr();
    printf("INGRESE UN NUMERO ENTERO: ");
    scanf("%d",&AUX->info);
    AUX->sig=CAB; //El puntero al siguiente nodo sea nulo (CAB es nulo)
    AUX->ant=CAB; //El puntero al anterior nodo sea nulo (CAB es nulo)
    if(CAB==NULL){ //Pregunto si CAB es igual igual a Nulo
        CAB=AUX;
        P=AUX;/*La primera ejecución de este método P ya no es NULL pero P está apuntando a AUX */
    }else{ //ESTO SI
        while(P->sig!=CAB){
            P=P->sig;
        }
    }
    P->sig=AUX; //El puntero siguiente de P toma el valor de AUX
    AUX->ant=P;
    CAB->ant=AUX;
}

void eliminardespues(){
    int x;
    clrscr();
    printf("INGRESE UN NUMERO PARA ELIMINAR EL SIGUIENTE: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    FD=CAB;
    QD=CAB;
    while(FD->info!=x&&FD->sig!=CAB){ //si lo que voy a eliminar es distinto al n?mero que me ingresaron y si hay otro
        FD=FD->sig; //paso al siguiente nodo
    }
    QD=FD->sig;
    if(FD->sig==CAB&&FD->info==x){
        printf("\nES LA CABECERA! NO SE PUEDE ELIMINAR");
    }else
       if(FD->sig==CAB&&FD->info!=x){
        printf("\nEL NUMERO INGRESADO NO SE ENCUENTRA EN LA LISTA");
    }else{
           FD->sig=QD->sig;
           (QD->sig)->ant=FD;
           printf("\nELIMINADO %d",QD->info);
           free(QD); //liberar el espacio en memoeria ocupado por QD
       }
       getch();
}

void eliminarantes()
{
    int xd;
    clrscr();
    printf("INGRESE UN NUMERO PARA ELIMINAR EL ANTERIOR: ");
    scanf("%d",&xd);

    Fd=CAB;
    Qd=CAB;
    while(Fd->info!=xd){
        Fd=Fd->ant;
    } Qd=Fd->ant;

    if(Fd==CAB){
        printf("\nES LA CABECERA! NO SE PUEDE ELIMINAR");
    }else{
        if(Qd==CAB){
            CAB=CAB->sig;
            Fd->ant=Qd->ant;
            (Fd->ant)->sig=Fd;
            printf("\nELIMINADO %d",Qd->info);
        }else{
            Fd->ant=Qd->ant;
            (Qd->ant)->sig=Fd;
            printf("\nELIMINADO %d",Qd->info);
        }
        free(Qd);
    }
    getch();
}

void visualizard(void)
{
    clrscr();
    if(CAB==NULL){
        printf("LISTA VACIA");
        getchar();
        return;
    }
    AUX=CAB;
    printf("LISTA:\n\n");
    while(AUX->sig!=CAB){
        printf("->%d\n",AUX->info);
        AUX=AUX->sig;
    }
    if(AUX->sig==CAB){
        printf("->%d\n",AUX->info);
    }
    getch();
}

void visualizari(void)
{
    clrscr();
    if(CAB==NULL){
        printf("LISTA VACIA");
        getchar();
        return;
    }
    AUX=CAB->ant;
    printf("LISTA:\n\n");
    do{
        printf("->%d\n",AUX->info);
        AUX=AUX->ant;
    }while(AUX->sig!=CAB);
    getch();
}

void clrscr()
{
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD coord = {0, 0};
    DWORD count;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi);
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, ' ', csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y, coord, &count);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, coord);
}
```

Comment: Seguramente alguien te agradecerá que publiques una solución completa... sin embargo, para futuras preguntas, recuerda que SO no es como un taller... que tu dejas el coche y ellos se encargan de arreglar todo lo que encuentren... si preguntas sobre un error en concreto lo normal es que las respuestas se ciñan a ese error, llegando a obviar todo lo demás.

Answer (score 1):

Al iniciar el programa `P` se inicializa a 0:

```
struct lista
{
    int info;
    struct lista *sig,*ant;
}*CAB=NULL,*AUX=NULL,*Q=NULL,*P=NULL,*F=NULL,*QD=NULL,*FD=NULL;
//                            ^^^^^^
```

Y sin embargo a la hora de insertar el primer elemento en la lista haces esto:

```
    P->sig=AUX;
```

`P` no apunta a una dirección de memoria válida. En consecuencia `P->sig` tampoco. Al Sistema Operativo no le suele gustar demasiado que un programa escriba en memoria que no le corresponde porque tiende a corromper la memoria de otros procesos... así que al detectar ese acceso se cura en salud y mata tu programa.

La solución pasa por implementar la lista doblemente enlazada de forma correcta. Esto es: solo necesitas un puntero al primer elemento de la lista:

```
struct lista
{
    int info;
    struct lista *sig,*ant;
} * raiz = NULL; // Intenta no usar variables globales
```

Para insertar un elemento simplemente se añade al final de este puntero:

```
void insertard(void)
{
    // prefiero calloc porsque incializa todos los bytes a 0
    struct lista* nuevo = (struct lista *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct lista));

    system("cls");
    printf("INGRESE UN NUMERO ENTERO:");
    scanf("%d",&nuevo->info);

    if( raiz == NULL ) // Si es el primer elemento de la lista
    {
      nuevo->sig = nuevo;
      nuevo->ant = nuevo;
      raiz = nuevo;
    }
    else // En caso contrario, añadimos el nodo al final de la lista
    {
      struct lista* ultimo = raiz->ant;
      ultimo->sig = nuevo;
      nuevo->ant = ultimo;

      nuevo->sig = raiz;
      raiz->ant = nuevo;
    }
}
```

Y ya está... no hacen falta más punteros. Si eso, a modo de ayuda, puedes usar un puntero que apunte al último de la lista... te simplificará el código necesario para añadir elementos al final (no tendrás que iterar la lista cada vez) y recorrer la lista en orden inverso pero te complicará en el sentido de que tendrás que gestionar dos punteros... esta parte corre de tu cuenta.

Comment: Si, pero me gustaría usar las variables del programa, no otras inventadas

Comment: @AlejandroCaro puedes cambiar `raiz` por `CAB` sin problemas... pero mi intención es que la respuesta sea entendible por la mayor cantidad de personas posibles... incluyéndote a ti. Si te pongo una respuesta que te maree con punteros y variables ininteligibles no vas a entender la solución.

Comment: Ahora cuando le doy para visualizar aparece el número que ingresé (por ejemplo un 4) LISTA: 4-> y después el programa se cuelga. El último nodo debe estar mal apuntado o algo así

Comment: @AlejandroCaro no he arreglado todos los métodos sino solamente lo que estaba relacionado con la pregunta. Obviamente si el diseño que habías pensado no es correcto eso afecta a todo el sistema