# Leer el siguiente elemento de la lista

Tags: c, lista

Tengo este programa que no tira error, pero el procedimiento visualizari solo muestra el primer elemento de la lista ¿Cómo hago para que siga imprimiendo los siguientes elementos de la lista?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct lista
{
    int info;
    struct lista *sig,*ant;
}*CAB=NULL,*AUX=NULL,*Q=NULL,*P=NULL,*F=NULL,*QD=NULL,*FD=NULL;

int main() {
    void insertard(void);
    void extraerd(void);
    void visualizard(void);
    void visualizari(void);
    void eliminardespues();
    void eliminarantes();
    char opc;
    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("___________________________________________________\n");
        printf("_¡¡¡MENU DE LISTA CIRCULAR DOBLEMENTE ENLAZADA!!!__\n");
        printf("___________________________________________________\n");
        printf("____________SELECCIONE UNA OPCION__________________\n");
        printf("___________________________________________________\n");
        printf("___________________________________________________\n");
        printf("__________1) INSERTAR______________________________\n");
        printf("__________2) VISUALIZAR ASCENDIENTE________________\n");
        printf("__________3) VISUALIZAR DESCENDIENTE_______________\n");
        printf("__________4) INGRESAR Y ELIMINAR SIGUIENTE_________\n");
        printf("__________5) INGRESAR Y ELIMINAR ANTERIOR__________\n");
        printf("__________6) SALIR_________________________________\n");
        printf("___________________________________________________\n");
        opc=getch();
        switch(opc)
        {
        case '1':
            insertard();
            break;
        case '2':
            visualizard();
            break;
        case '3':
            visualizari();
            break;
        case '4':
            eliminardespues();
            break;
        case '5':
            eliminarantes();
            break;
        }
    } while(opc!='6');
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void insertard(void)
{
    P=CAB;
    AUX=(struct lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    system("cls");
    printf("INGRESE UN NUMERO ENTERO: ");
    scanf("%d",&AUX->info);
    AUX->sig=CAB;
    AUX->ant=CAB;
    F=AUX;
    if(CAB==NULL){
        CAB=AUX;
        P=AUX;
    }else{
        while (P->sig!=CAB){
            P=P->sig;
    }
    }
        P->sig=AUX;
        AUX->ant=P;
        AUX->sig=CAB;
}
void eliminardespues(){
    int x;
    system("cls");
    printf("INGRESE UN NUMERO PARA ELIMINAR EL SIGUIENTE: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    FD=CAB;
    QD=CAB;
    while(FD->info!=x&&FD->sig!=CAB){
    FD=FD->sig;
    }QD=FD->sig;

    if(FD->sig==CAB&&FD->info!=x){
        printf("\nEL NUMERO INGRESADO NO SE ENCUENTA EN LA LISTA");
    }else{
        if(FD->info==x){
            FD->sig=QD->sig;
            (QD->sig)->ant=FD;
            printf("\nELIMINADO %d",QD->info);
            free(QD);
        }
    }
    getch();
}

void eliminarantes()
{
    int x;
    system("cls");
    printf("INGRESE UN NUMERO PARA ELIMINAR EL ANTERIOR");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    FD=CAB;
    QD=CAB;
    while (FD->info!=x&&FD->sig!=CAB){
        FD=FD->sig;
    }QD=FD->ant;
    if(FD->sig==CAB&&FD->info!=x){
        printf("\nEL NUMERO INGRESADO NO SE ENCUENTA EN LA LISTA");
    }else{
        if(FD->info==x){
            FD->ant=QD->ant;
            (QD->ant)->sig=FD;
            printf("\nELIMINADO %d",QD->info);
            free(QD);
        }
    }
    getch();
}

void visualizard(void)
{
    system("cls");
    if(CAB==NULL){
        printf("LISTA VACIA");
        getchar();
        return;
    }
    AUX=CAB;
    printf("LISTA:\n\n");
    while(AUX->sig!=CAB){
        printf("-> %d\n",AUX->info);
        AUX=AUX->sig;
    }
    if(AUX->sig==CAB){
        printf("-> %d\n",AUX->info);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Esta función falla:

```
void visualizari(void){
    system("cls");
    if(F==NULL){
        printf("LISTA VACIA");
        getchar();
        return;
    }
    AUX=F;
    printf("LISTA:\n\n");
    do{
        printf("-> %d\n",AUX->info);
        AUX=AUX->ant;
    }while(AUX->sig!=CAB);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Pon el código completo, pero quizás sea lo que dice @Trauma avanza al puntero siguiente y no a anterior como tienes puesto

Comment: Por supuesto. El código completo se encuentra aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107177/lista-circular-doblemente-enlazada/107187?noredirect=1#comment199051_107187

Comment: Y no has hecho ningún cambio desde que publicaste la primera pregunta??? aunque solo sea porque incorporaste los cambios que te comenté el código ya no es el mismo que el que referencias...

Comment: ya corregí el código del ingreso pero el procedimiento visualizari sigue con error

Answer (score 2):

Tu programa no funciona. Te empeñas (y no entiendo el motivo) en seguir prácticas que te están llevando por el camino de la amargura:

- Variables globales: **No las uses**. No necesitas recurrir a ellas. Bajo su apariencia dócil y sencilla se esconden un montón de errores complicados de entender y detectar.
- Usar tus variables: Puedes darle el nombre que quieras a las variables... ¿por qué eliges nombres crípticos? ¿Por qué usas tantas variables? Una lista enlazada doble solo necesita para funcionar **un único puntero** a uno de los nodos. Luego, para operaciones varias, pongamos como mucho un par más, siendo estos locales). Eso dan 3 punteros, mientras que tu programa está usando 7 y **todos globales**.

Al ser globales su valor dependerá de lo que hayas hecho en operaciones anteriores. ¿Estás seguro de que los valores de los punteros son válidos independiemente de la secuencia de operaciones que realices?

Vamos a verlo en perspectiva: Imagínate que para poder vivir tuvieses que contraer manualmente el músculo del corazón (controlando tanto el ritmo como la presión que haces en cada bombeo para no desmayarte y no provocarte embolias por exceso de presión) y lo mismo para la respiración. Además imagínate que tienes que encargarte de mover la musculatura de tu estómago para poder hacer la digestión y lo propio para que los intestinos puedan mover los bolos alimenticios... el sistema resultante no te permitiría dormir ni pensar en algo que no fuese mantenerte con vida... el sistema no es viable y eso mismo te está pasando a tí.

Tu programa no llega, o no debería, llegar a visualizar datos porque falla al insertar un segundo elemento. ¿Por qué? Varios motivos:

```
void insertard(void)
{
    P=CAB; // 2
    AUX=(struct lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    system("cls");
    printf("INGRESE UN NUMERO ENTERO:");
    scanf("%d",&AUX->info);
    AUX->sig=CAB; // 1,3
    AUX->ant=CAB; // 1,3
    F=AUX;
    if(CAB==NULL){
        CAB=AUX;
        P=AUX; // 2
    }else{
        while (P->sig!=CAB){ // 3
            P=P->sig;
    }
        P->sig=AUX; // 2
        AUX->ant=P; // 2
        AUX->sig=CAB;
    }
}
```

1. Una asignación fuera de lugar que no tiene sentido. Esto suena a... "*no tengo ni idea de donde voy a colocar el nodo pero voy a ir haciendo algo porque me lo piden*". Si algo no es necesario, **no lo hagas**. En este caso ya tendrías punteros inicializados... ¿cómo detectarías después que los punteros apuntan a donde deben? ya están inicializados, luego para distinguir entre un elemento bueno y uno malo te toca comparar direcciones de memoria
2. ¿Qué pinta `P` en todo esto? `P` no tiene ningún sentido en una lista vacía pero te empeñas en usarlo y esto tiene consecuencias...
3. Llegamos al premio gordo: Insertas el primer elemento, pese a que se supone que es una lista circular resulta que los punteros `sig` y `ant` apuntan a 0 (fíjate que `CAB` aun no apunta al nuevo nodo)... luego insertas un segundo elemento, con lo que `P` apunta al nodo de cabecera y al llegar al `while`... sorpresa!!! `P->sig == 0 != CAB`, luego saltas al puntero nulo y a partir de ahí se estropeó la fiesta.

El error es una suma de los 3 puntos comentados y ya te está enseñando que la lista está mal construida. E, insisto, te sobran punteros:

- Salvo `CAB` todos deberían ser punteros definidos en las funciones (y solo si hace falta)
- Para insertar un elemento al *final* de una lista circular (nota que al ser circular es infinita porque nunca llegas al final), basta con hacer:

  ```
  ultimoNodo = CAB->ant;
  ```

  Y es algo que tiene todo el sentido del mundo... si tienes una lista en la que los punteros `sig` siguen un recorrido tal que

  ```
  A -> B -> C -> A
  ```

  entonces los punteros `ant` hacen el siguiente recorrido:

  ```
  A <- B <- C <- A
  ```

  Pues bien, para encontrar el último nodo (en este caso `C`), podemos recorrer toda la lista usando `sig` (`A -> B -> C`) que implica un bucle y, en este caso concreto, tres saltos... o podemos usar el puntero `ant` (`C <- A`), que **siempre** implica un salto y no obliga a mantener punteros raros en la aplicación.

Ahora bien, suponiendo que, por misterios de la vida, tu programa no falla en este punto, llegamos a la función que comentas y encontramos que (asumiendo que el puntero `P` esté bien asignado) la comprobación del bucle no es correcta: `while(AUX->sig != CAB)`. Si estás en el último nodo de la lista circular... ¿A dónde apunta `AUX->sig`? exacto, al primer nodo de la lista, `CAB`... y ahí muere tu bucle. La comprobación debería ser `while(AUX!=CAB)`.

Por otro lado, insisto, tu código es excesivamente complejo para lo que tiene que hacer... y para muestra un botón:

```
void visualizari(void){
  system("cls");
  if(F==NULL){
    printf("LISTA VACIA");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("LISTA:\n\n");
    AUX = CAB->ant; // vamos al ultimo elemento
    do{
      printf("-> %d\n",AUX->info);
      AUX=AUX->ant;
    }while(AUX!=CAB);
  }
  getch();
}
```

Fíjate como el puntero `P` no es necesario en absoluto (una preocupación menos en tu programa)

Comment: Ahora muestra solo el primer elemento

Comment: @AlejandroCaro el problema es que la lista esta mal construída... has probado a depurar esa función?

Comment: Hice los cambios que sugeriste, pero vuelvo a repetir solo el primer elemento, no sé como corregir esto y estoy pidiendo ayuda, para eso está este sitio.

Comment: @AlejandroCaro he editado la respuesta sobre la inserción de eleemntos en la lista. A ver si eso te ayuda

Comment: No, tampoco me sirvió

Comment: @AlejandroCaro el sitio está para ayudar a responder preguntas... **concretas**. Corregir todo el ejercicio **no** es una pregunta concreta. La función que te he puesto en la respuesta funciona, ya que genera la lista de forma correcta... si tu programa sigue fallando se debe a otros problemas del código no contemplados por esta pregunta (por ejemplo tienes errores en la visualización). Si esta respueta no soluciona el problema planteado inicialmente entonces las opciones posiblemente pasen por cerrar la pregunta por ser poco clara e inespecífica.

Comment: Igual ya tengo el programa corregido

Comment: @AlejandroCaro no pierdas de vista que el objetivo de SO no es responderte a tí en exclusiva sino crear un sistema de preguntas y respuestas útil para el mayor número posible de usuarios... tu dejadez puede tener como resultado una menor participación de gente en tus preguntas.